# Trying to stitch one giant image using BigMap

Tags: openstreetmap, perl

I need to get one giant image from OpenStreetMap.  I have downloaded all the tiles I need using Maperitive and now I am trying to stitch all the tiles together using a script from http://bigmap.osmz.ru/index.html but my script keeps failing on the following line of code

```
my @layers = ('file:///Tiles/!z/!x/!y.png');
```

saying "Global symbol "@layers" requires explicit package name.

The original line of code from the website

```
my @layers = ('http://tile.openstreetmap.org/!z/!x/!y.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add "f:" to the location

```
my @layers = ('file:///f:/Tiles/!z/!x/!y.png');
```